# My C program crashes in its second loop and I don't know why

Tags: c

Its aim is to get a number from the user and create that number of kind of television programs and save their information based on structures. It gets the program name, hour, etc.

Unfortunately it crashes after getting the name in the second loop.

I have tried printing something in its second loop but it doesn't even reach that point.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

struct time {
    int hour;
    int minute;
};

struct program {
    char name[30];
    struct time mytime;
    int viewer[3];// baby  woman man 
    int type;
};

void func (struct program *, int, int);

struct program * func2 (struct program *);

int main()
{
    int k, i;

    printf("k=");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    struct program *p , *p1 , *p2;

    int size = sizeof(struct program);

    p = (struct program *) malloc (k * sizeof (struct program));

    p1= p;

    if (p != NULL)
    {

    for (i=0; i<k; i++)
    {

      printf("Name =");

      scanf("%s", p->name);

    //it crashes here !

      printf("Hour=");

      scanf("%d",&p->mytime.hour);

      printf("Minute=");

      scanf("%d",&p->mytime.minute);

      printf("Type=");

      scanf("%d",&p->type);

      printf("Baby=");
      scanf("%d",&p->viewer[0]);
      printf("Woman=");
      scanf("%d",&p->viewer[1]);
      printf("Man=");
      scanf("%d",&p->viewer[2]);

        printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");

        p += size;

    }

   }

    p=p1;

    func (p, size, k);

      printf("Name =");
      scanf("%s", p1->name);
      printf("Hour=");
      scanf("%d",&p1->mytime.hour);
      printf("Minute=");
      scanf("%d",&p1->mytime.minute);
      printf("Type=");
      scanf("%d",&p1->type);
      printf("Baby=");
      scanf("%d",&p1->viewer[0]);
      printf("Woman=");
      scanf("%d",&p1->viewer[1]);
      printf("Man=");
      scanf("%d",&p1->viewer[2]);
      printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");

    func2(p1);

    printf("%s %d  %d  %d  %d %d %d", p1->name, p1->mytime.hour,p1->mytime.minute, p1->type, 
           p1->viewer[0], p1->viewer[1], p1->viewer[2]);

    return 0;
}

void func (struct program *p, int size, int k)
{
    int i, s;

    for (i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
      s =  0.2*(p->viewer[0] + p->viewer[1] + p->viewer[2]);
      if (  p->viewer[0] > s ) 
         p->type= 1;    
      if (p->mytime.hour > 14  )    
      {
         printf("Name=%s Hour=%d   Minute=%d\n",p->name ,p->mytime.hour,p->mytime.minute);
      }
      p += size;    
    }   
}

struct program * func2 (struct program *p)
{
  if (p->viewer[1] > p->viewer[2])  
  {
    p->type = 3;
    return p;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your code properly, because your post is currently very hard to read. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you don't know how to format the code. Also, please read at least the following pages to quickly learn how to use Stack Overflow: [tour], [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> p += size;
> ```

C knows the size. You need

```
p += 1 /* C multiplies by size automagically */;
```